# Switching from Basic Authentication to OAuth 2.0 for Django & Tastypie

Tags: ios, django, authentication, oauth, tastypie

I'm a self taught back end engineer so I'm learning all of this stuff as I go along. For the longest time, I've been using basic authentication for my users. As long as you have the right username and password, you can access all the Tastypie API resources.

Many developers are advising against this approach since each request will contain the username & password. Anyone with the right skills can listen in on the connection between my iOS application and my Django Server and obtain their password.

I wouldn't want to put my user's credentials at risk so I would like to implement a more secure way of authentication. I've been doing a lot of reading and came across OAuth 2.0 which  has the whole token approach. The only time when the username and the password is sent to the server is when they are requesting an access token.

After the access token is given (each user will have a unique access token), that token is used to authenticate instead of the username and password.

This way, anyone listening in will only see the token. If the token is exposed, I can easily remove the old token and generate a new token for the user.

Along side this, I would like to make it so that only requests coming from my iOS application are able to access the tastypie resources.(I'm thinking of generating a application key for my app and if third party services want to use the service, I will grant them a unique key as well)

How can go about implementing this into my Django setup? Can I use OAuth2.0 do to this? If I implement this setup, how can I make it so that attackers are unable to obtain the application token?

Comment: I'm not sure on the Django side of things, but I have used GTMOAuth2 which uses the Google Auth for iOS apps, maybe you can check that out as a good 3rd party authentication method. The link is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gtm-oauth2

Comment: The only real way to make attackers unable to obtain your application tokens is to avoid generating them at all. There might be a hole at any point in your software stack and whoops - all your tokens are compromised. The point is whether the data you are protecting with your authentication method is worth trying to break it. If it's a simple website, then why not keep using `Basic Auth`. But if you are really into `OAuth2`, [here](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/building-a-true-oauth-20-api-with-django-and-tasty-pie.html) is a simple how-to.

Comment: @kroolik I understand what you are saying but there is a slight problem with that approach. Sure, it could be a simple website that no cares about. BUT! Anyone who is using something like WireShark can sniff on the packets being sent between the application and the server. Most users use the same password for all their online accounts. This is why having Basic Auth will not do justice.

Comment: @RiegieGodwin, if someone is using WireShark, then they can sniff either your app id, secret or access token. If you are concerned about eavesdropping, try using SSL.

Comment: @kroolik that's a really good suggestion, I'm going to try the SSL approach, it seems more promising

Comment: @kroolik, I've implemented SSL. For an extra layer of security, do you suggest I also implement OAuth?

Comment: @RiegieGodwin, if you've got SSL set up, then capturing the data transferred requires a MIM or other attack similar in difficulty. Now considering someone has done it and you've implemented `OAuth2` then the attacker has either your app id/secret/access token. You can try `OAuth` which does message signing, but still. If you want to be really secure, you'd better transfer your secret over another communication channel and use it to encrypt your data. But that would ruin the point of SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the this project - https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth.

And It's Docs - http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/

It is a great and live project that is up to date with the latest version of Django.

It has integrated social auth for Django with a variety of platforms.